# Breadth's Algorithm Runs Forever Despite Possible Ending

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, breadth-first-search, path-finding

So I saw this coding interview question and tried to solve it. I am trying to employ Breadth's Path Finding Algorithm to find the optimum flight routes from a given airport to all other airports; given the list of all airports and routes. An element in routes means that there is a one way flight from the first airport to the second one.

I got here, this was supposed to find the shortest routes to all other airports from a given airport. But when I run it never ends.

I figured that my algorithm doesn't append all possible next airports to my paths, but everything seems o.k to me.

'''

```
import queue

airports = ["BGI", "CDG", "DEL", "DOH", "DSM", "EWR", "EYW", "HND", "ICN", "JFK", "LGA",
            "LHR", "ORD", "SAN", "SFO", "SIN", "TLV", "BUD"]

routes = [["DSM", "ORD"], ["ORD", "BGI"], ["BGI", "LGA"], ["SIN", "CDG"], ["CDG", "SIN"],
          ["CDG", "BUD"], ["DEL", "DOH"], ["DEL", "CDG"], ["TLV", "DEL"], ["EWR", "HND"],
          ["HND", "ICN"], ["HND", "JFK"], ["ICN", "JFK"], ["JFK", "LGA"], ["EYW", "LHR"],
          ["LHR", "SFO"], ["SFO", "SAN"], ["SFO", "DSM"], ["SAN", "EYW"], ["LGA", "EYW"]]

main = "LGA"

def done(moves, aim):
    if moves == "":
        return False
    elif moves[-1][1] == aim:
        return True
    return False

def valid(moves, put):
    if moves == "":
        return False
    if moves[-1][1] == put[0]:
        return True
    return False

def available_starts(start, pos):
    anfaenge = list()
    for i in pos:
        if i[0] == start:
            anfaenge.append(i)
    return anfaenge


#MAIN ALGORITHM
kurzeste_moeglichkeiten = [] """all shortest possibilities"""
for port in airports:
    nums = queue.Queue()
    nums.put("")
    add = ""
    start = main
    if port != start:
        anfaenge = available_starts(start, routes) """possible startings"""
        for anfang in anfaenge:
            anfang = [anfang]
            nums.put(anfang)
        while not done(add, port):
            add = nums.get()
            for got in routes:
                if valid(add, got):
                    t = add
                    t.append(got)
                    nums.put(t)
        kurzeste_moeglichkeiten.append(add)

for eine in kurzeste_moeglichkeiten:
    print(eine)
```

'''

Comment: I figured some are not possible, yet if I run the code just for the possible ones it still runs forever...

Comment: Toy say this runs forever, but you did not even check to see which of the loops is the one at fault. This can be easily done by adding some debugging `print` calls in your code.

Comment: Since this is for an interview, this would be a good time to show off your debugging skills, or learn them if you have none. (also "breadth" is a word, not a name)

Comment: You should use a module to handle tree structure like ‘anytree’. This would help you building the code by putting appart all tree/node management. You could then focus on the Breadth algorithm.

Comment: For what is worth, you have to legs that will loop infintely : ["SIN", "CDG"] and ["CDG", "SIN"]

Comment: BTW, this is the problem behind this Youtube video "Google Coding Interview With A High School Student"

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to represent your graph with the modules `networkx` and `matplotlib`. As you can see, the airports are splitted in 2 groups.
As mentionned, I do believe 2 of your routes `["SIN", "CDG"]` and `["CDG", "SIN"]` are the reverse ones and are not OK with the rest of your data.

[image]
NOTE: the code I've used to show the graph:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
airports = ["BGI", "CDG", "DEL", "DOH", "DSM", "EWR", "EYW", "HND", "ICN", "JFK", "LGA",
            "LHR", "ORD", "SAN", "SFO", "SIN", "TLV", "BUD"]
legs = [["DSM", "ORD"], ["ORD", "BGI"], ["BGI", "LGA"], ["SIN", "CDG"], ["CDG", "SIN"],
          ["CDG", "BUD"], ["DEL", "DOH"], ["DEL", "CDG"], ["TLV", "DEL"], ["EWR", "HND"],
          ["HND", "ICN"], ["HND", "JFK"], ["ICN", "JFK"], ["JFK", "LGA"], ["EYW", "LHR"],
          ["LHR", "SFO"], ["SFO", "SAN"], ["SFO", "DSM"], ["SAN", "EYW"], ["LGA", "EYW"]]
main = "LGA"
G = nx.Graph()
for node in airports:
    G.add_node(node)
for leg in legs:
    G.add_edge(leg[0], leg[1])
plt.subplot(121)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```